# Does the git status really calculate and check the SHA over a content of the entire working directory?

Tags: git, sha

When I make the SHA1 calculation on some file using some tool for this (e.g. the HashCalc), it takes some time if the file is a little bit larger (e.g. 1GB and more). But if I run the git status over repository of the size of 5GB or more, it seems as the git status checks the files for changes for no more than a few seconds.

Now, the question is whether the git status really calculates and checks the SHA of the files, or it just compares the time and date the files are last modified against the records in the index?

Answer (score 0):

The `git status` command does not compute any hashes.<sup>1</sup>

What `git status` does is:

- print information about the current branch, which involves reading the `HEAD` file and maybe a few more small files;
- compare (as in `git diff --name-status`) every file in the `HEAD` commit with every file in the index; and
- compare (as in `git diff --name-status`) every file in the index with every file in your work-tree.

The output section where `git status` shows *changes to be committed* and *changes not staged for commit* are just reformatted versions of the results of the two `git diff --name-status`-es.

These two relatively massive `git diff`s *could* take a long time, but they don't.  That is for two different reasons:

1. With `--name-status`, a comparison of two commits, or one commit and the index, can go very fast, because every file *in* a commit is stored via something Git calls a *tree object*, and the index has a form that is very much like a flattened series of tree objects.  The files that are in the commit, and that are in the index, all have pre-computed hashes.  The difference operation can just compare the hashes to find out if the file is different.  (Presence or absence of a file determines *added* and *removed* statuses.  Rename detection, if it has to run, can be slow.)
2. With `--name-status`, a comparison of the index and your work-tree can go pretty fast because the index *caches* information *about* your work-tree.<sup>2</sup>  For each file for which the cache data are valid, Git does not have to look inside the work-tree file.  For files where the cache data aren't valid, Git can sometimes know immediately that the work-tree copy of the file does not match the index copy.  This generally leaves only a few tough cases where Git really does have to verify that the work-tree copy does or does not match the index copy.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, there's a consistency-check hash in the index, and it does read the index, so there's one hash.  But that's for the *index*, which is not a file you can commit.

<sup>2</sup>The main speed bottleneck here is how fast your OS can do `lstat` system calls.  Or at least, that's supposed to be where it is; some versions of Git accidentally introduced some quadratic behavior in some corner cases.  If lstat calls *are* slow, you can disable them on specific files with `git update-index --assume-unchanged`, though this means Git just assumes the file was not changed.  This "skip slow lstat" was its original purpose.  Git is allowed to stat the file anyway, which is why `--skip-worktree` is recommended for hiding work-tree changes.